# How to check if data-rate of option is same as another selected option, then do not add to total?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a city drop down list in my checkout page. Shipping charges add in total amount of order depends upon the selected city.

If I have an option with the same data-rate value, it adds value in total every time I change city in drop down list.

I want if dropdown option have same data-rate value then it does not add again in total amount.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery('#city').change(function() {
  var c = jQuery(this).find(':selected').data('rate');
  c = parseFloat(c);

  jQuery('#shipping').html(c);

  var d = jQuery('#total').html();
  d = parseFloat(d);
  d = d + c;
  jQuery('#total').html(d);
  var e = jQuery('#ordertotal').html();
  e = parseFloat(e);
  e = e + c;
  jQuery('#ordertotal').html(e);

  jQuery('#orderField').val(e);
  jQuery('#shippingRate').val(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label>City</label>
  <select id="city" class=" select city" name="city" required="true">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select The City</option>
    <option data-rate="199" value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="" disabled>Punjab Cities</option>
    <option data-rate="199" value="Ahmed Nager Chatha">Ahmed Nager Chatha</option>
    <option data-rate="199" value="Ahmadpur East">Ahmadpur East</option>
    <option data-rate="199" value="Ali Khan Abad">Ali Khan Abad</option>
    <option data-rate="199" value="Alipur">Alipur</option>
  </select>
<div id="shipping"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: _"I want if dropdown option have same data-rate value it don't add again"_ - what if there was also an option with a different value? Say, you add 199 first, but then you select an option with value 123 - then you would not want those 123 to be added on top of those already added 199 either, right? Instead of trying to remember which selections happened, you should rather keep your total without the shipping in a separate variable - so that you can calculate total plus shipping anew again, each time an option gets selected.

Comment: Thanks brother for your reply, let me try this